# Dompdf download ask for save Adobe Reader at close

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I'm making a download of PDF with DOMPDF. Everything is working fine. The PDF is downloading and opens well in Adobe Reader. But at closing the window, Adobe Reader is asking me if I want to save the PDF file where I didn't change anything in. What is the possible problem that cause this problem?

```
$filename = $naam.' Factsheet.pdf';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();

file_put_contents('pdf/'.$filename, $dompdf->output( array("compress" => 0) ));

if ( !headers_sent() ) {
  $dompdf->stream($filename, $options);
}
```

Can please anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure about the file path that you have given? try using custom file path file_put_contents('yourpath/Factsheet.pdf', $dompdf->output( array("compress" => 0) ));

Comment: The folder pdf/ exists in the root of my public_html. The folder also is writeable for the server and the PDF's are in the PDF folder on the server. That's is all working fine. But after download and opening the PDF. Adobe Reader is asking to save the changes to the PDF file while there is nothing changed after opening.

Comment: Is there any message(s) given by the adobe reader like repairing or something? when opening the pdf file?

Comment: Only a message after clicking close. It is asking if i want to save changes. I can choose yes, no or cancel

Comment: $filename = $naam.' Factsheet.pdf'; FYI: your file name has a space. is it a writing mistake or as it is in the code? what is the file name you get when you down load the pdf file? try to locate to the downloaded file and try to rename it. find out if there is any space. verify the file name is ok with the downloaded one with the ext as well.

Comment: The space is not a mistake. I can make the space an underscore but that won't fix the problem. If i'm looking on the FTP for de PDF it has the name Indian Summer Factsheet.pdf. After downloading from the browser I get the message to save the PDF but if I manually download the PDF from the FTP and open it I don't get that message.

Comment: What about leaving $options as default? file_put_contents('pdf/'.$filename, $dompdf->output()); $dompdf->stream($filename);

Comment: With the default option the download still works and still the question if i want to save the changes

Comment: Almost certainly your PDF file is broken in some way and Adobe Reader is repairing it silently when opened. Because it's changed it then asks to save  when closing. Can you post an example PDF file so that I can run it through a preflight tool?

Comment: Second @DavidvanDriessche's comment. Just wanted to add that you should make sure you're using the latest version (currently 0.6.1).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for grave digging, but i had the same issue, however i fixed my code but i dont know how, here is the working code

```
$filename = $sm_number . "_" . date('Ymd') .'_OK_CALCOOLING.pdf';


use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($content);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$array = array(
    "compress" => 0,
    "Attachment" => 0
);


$dompdf->stream($filename, $array);
```

Comment: Might be a little late, but it'll help others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching. And that's worth it; no need to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `ob_get_clean()` when declaring your `$html` variable.

```
$html = ob_get_clean(); //ADD THIS LINE WHEN DECLARING HTML VARIABLE
$html .= 'My content here';

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->getOptions()->setIsFontSubsettingEnabled(true);
$dompdf->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("filename.pdf", array("compress" => 0, "Attachment" => false));
exit;
```